# Trying to update Boolean variable with 0 value but it remain unchanged

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update a `Boolean` `field` in my `views.py`
Code:

```
try:
    t = Rating.objects.get(answer_id=request.POST.get("answer", ""), user_id=request.POST.get("user", ""))
    if request.POST.get("rating", 0) == 0:
        t.rating = False
    else:
        t.rating = True
    t.save(update_fields=['rating'])
except Rating.DoesNotExist: 
    form.save(commit=True)
```

But if the previous value is 1 and I'm trying to pass false it remain unchanged. And if previous value is 0 and I trying to pass 1 it will update very well. Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in `request.POST` are always strings, so your condition will never be true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have another issue i am sending value 0 as POST for field rating but as you have said values in request.POST are always strings therefore when i am saving my form it always store value 1 for field rating. Anything i can do not to have always value 1?

Answer (score 0):

Strings never equal to numbers so you should compare to `"0"` instead of `0`:

```
if request.POST.get("rating", "0") == "0":
```

BTW, you can refactor your `if` statement to simple assignment:

```
t.rating = request.POST.get("rating", "0") != "0"
```